# Pip install only pure-python packages

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to configure pip to install only pure-python packages with pure-python dependencies? I'd like to be able to write a python project that is compatible with both Jython and CPython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the file that implements the various command line options for pip and reading the documentation, it would appear that none of these options have the ability to exclude packages based on this criterion. `--no-binary` and `--only-binary` seem to deal with compilation in general rather than excluding packages with non-python content.

https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/de6e4b5c9ea942e6c961066f1ad7f5398b730dfa/pip/cmdoptions.py

The python wheel PEP has metadata that shows what part of the package is a purelib and gets expanded into `site-packages`, and a `Root-Is-Purelib` boolean field which seems to indicate that the entire package is pure python. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0491/ It might be possible to configure pip to exclude everything but wheels and then filter the wheels based on metadata.

The deprecated `--use-wheel` flag seems to cause pip to prefer wheels, but not to exclude non-wheels. There does not seem to be a way to block wheels from being installed based on their metadata.

Comment: Searching for ['cpython'](https://github.com/pypa/pip/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cpython&type=Code) and ['jython'](https://github.com/pypa/pip/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jython&type=Code) in the pip code doesn't show anything that would allow for making this distinction either.

Comment: Right now I'm reading the wheel PEP to see if there's any metadata I could use to exclude packages with native code.